# Cerrar la conexión a base de datos MySQL de un formulario con PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

He creado un formulario de registro para ingresar datos en una base de datos MySQL, en mi formulario está el botón de "registro" donde registra los datos escritos en los inputs, el primer registro que realicé fué correcto y agregué un mensaje que se realizó correctamente, sin embargo cada vez que abro dicha pagina me crea valores NULL por lo cual me crea registros vacios en mi base de datos, mi pregunta es:

**¿Cómo puedo cerrar la conexion para que cada vez que abra la pagina deje de crear registros vacios o se cree el registro hasta que apriete el boton?**

He investigado y sé de las "conexiones persistentes" y al parecer es mi caso, pero no estoy muy seguro, este es mi codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/701554467301421056/1rvQ3_tU.jpg"><title>Captura de datos</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$usuario = "usuario";
$contra = "contraseña";
$bd = "base de datos";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contra, $bd) or die("<h2>Error al conectar</h2>");

$cct = $_POST['cct'];
$cdt = $_POST['centroTrab'];
$muni = $_POST['municipio'];
$mod = $_POST['modalidad'];
$calnd = $_POST['calendario'];

$insertar = "INSERT into BDCALENDARIO (CCT, CENTRO_DE_TRABAJO, MUNICIPIO, MODALIDAD, CALENDARIO)". "VALUES ('$cct', '$cdt', '$muni', '$mod', '$calnd')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar)or die("<h2>Error al isnertar registros</h2>");
echo "¡Gracais! Hemos recibido sus datos.";
?>
<center>
</br>
<h1><font size="10">Captura tus datos aqui!</font></h1></br>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <table>
                <tr><td>CCT: </td><td><input type="text" name="cct"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Centro De Trabajo: </td><td><input type="text" name="centroTrab"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Municipio:</td><td> <input type="text" name="municipio"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Modalidad:</td><td> <input type="text" name="modalidad"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Calendario:</td><td> <input type="text" name="calendario"></td></tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="btnRegistrar">
    </form>
    </br>
    </br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Antes de empezar

El acceso a los elementos de los arreglos superglobales *(POST, GET)* de una manera directa no esta recomendado en PHP.

*Por lo tanto:*

Lo primero que te recomiendo es que sustituyas el valor de estas variables:

```
$cct = $_POST['cct'];
$cdt = $_POST['centroTrab'];
$muni = $_POST['municipio'];
$mod = $_POST['modalidad'];
$calnd = $_POST['calendario'];
```

Por:

```
$cct = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cct", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$cdt = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "centroTrab", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$muni = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "municipio", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mod = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "modalidad", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$calnd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "calendario", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

#### ¿Que hicimos aqui?

Cambiamos la forma de acceder a los datos recibidos via *POST*, usando la funcion [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php) de PHP, a esta funcion le indicamos:

- Origen de las variables (INPUT_POST)
- Nombre de la variable
- Bandera, esta se usa para "limpiar" los valores que recibiras del formulario.

**Teniendo en cuenta esto**

Tu codigo de PHP, no tiene alguna sentencia que valide si:

```
<input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="btnRegistrar">
```

**FUE** o **NO FUE** presionado. Es decir cuando envias tu formulario , se envia un variable dentro de *POST* que se ha de llamar *btnRegistrar*, es decir, si validas la existencia de esta variable, indica que realmente se presiono el boton "Registrar".

#### ¿Como podemos validar esto?

Si bien podemos usar la funcion [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) de PHP, ya debemos tener en cuenta lo explicado anteriomente, respecto a acceder dichos valores directamente.

Pero! La funcion [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php) cuenta con distintos valores de retorno.

*Segun [documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php#refsect1-function.filter-input-returnvalues) de PHP*

> En caso de éxito, valor de la variable pedida, FALSE si el filtro falla o NULL si la variable variable_name no está definida. Si se usa el flag FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE, retorna FALSE si la variable no está definida y NULL si el filtro falla.

#### En conclusion

Tu codigo deberia quedar asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/701554467301421056/1rvQ3_tU.jpg"><title>Captura de datos</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

/* Validamos que se haya presionado el boton 'btnRegistrar' */
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "btnRegistrar", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) != NULL){

$server = "localhost";
$usuario = "usuario";
$contra = "contraseña";
$bd = "base de datos";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contra, $bd) or die("<h2>Error al conectar</h2>");

$cct = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cct", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$cdt = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "centroTrab", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$muni = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "municipio", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$mod = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "modalidad", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$calnd = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "calendario", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$insertar = "INSERT into BDCALENDARIO (CCT, CENTRO_DE_TRABAJO, MUNICIPIO, MODALIDAD, CALENDARIO)". "VALUES ('$cct', '$cdt', '$muni', '$mod', '$calnd')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar)or die("<h2>Error al isnertar registros</h2>");
echo "¡Gracais! Hemos recibido sus datos.";

}

?>
<center>
</br>
<h1><font size="10">Captura tus datos aqui!</font></h1></br>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <table>
                <tr><td>CCT: </td><td><input type="text" name="cct"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Centro De Trabajo: </td><td><input type="text" name="centroTrab"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Municipio:</td><td> <input type="text" name="municipio"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Modalidad:</td><td> <input type="text" name="modalidad"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Calendario:</td><td> <input type="text" name="calendario"></td></tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="btnRegistrar">
    </form>
    </br>
    </br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionó de maravilla, muchas gracias amigo, me ayudaste bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Debes validar la parte del php en la que recibes los datos del form y guardas, con

```html
if(isset($_POST['btnRegistrar']) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_REQUEST))
{

$server = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$contra = "";
$bd = "";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contra, $bd) or die("<h2>Error al conectar</h2>");

$cct = $_POST['cct'];
$cdt = $_POST['centroTrab'];
$muni = $_POST['municipio'];
$mod = $_POST['modalidad'];
$calnd = $_POST['calendario'];

$insertar = "INSERT into BDCALENDARIO (CCT, CENTRO_DE_TRABAJO, MUNICIPIO, MODALIDAD, CALENDARIO)". "VALUES ('$cct', '$cdt', '$muni', '$mod', '$calnd')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar)or die("<h2>Error al isnertar registros</h2>");
echo "¡Gracais! Hemos recibido sus datos.";
}

?>
```